# Use Mysql results to assign $_POST variables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, http-post

I have a table in my Database which contains the Languages my website is translated to .. let's say i have EN, AR, and KU

the form is like below:

```
<form id="addTags">
  <label>Friendly Name</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="FriendlyName" id="FriendlyName" /><br />
  <span style="font-size:9pt;color:#555;"><i>This is used to mark the Category</i></span><br />
  <label>URL ShortCode</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="ShortName" id="ShortName" /><br />
  <h3>
    Translate for multilingual use <span style="font-size:9pt;color:red;"><i>*Required</i></span>
  </h3><label>عربي</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="AR" id="AR" /><br />
  <label>English</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="EN" id="EN" /><br />
  <label>Kurdish</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="KU" id="KU" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Cat" class="button" align="center" />
</form>
```

the last three text inputs are dynamically added depending on the languages in the table i mentioned.
my question is .. if i add a fourth language, how can i catch the $_POST parameters dynamically in my php script? i was thinking of getting the Langs from the same table and assign them as variables. but is it possible to do something like this?

```
<?
while($lang =$result->fetch_array()){
 $langID=$lang['langid'];
 $input_$langID=$_POST['$langID'];
}
?>
```

QUICL EDIT
done a similar thing .. here's the quick result

```
$get_lang_id = $link->query("SELECT * FROM `tjcgLangs`");
$where = "";
$FriendlyName=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['FriendlyName']);
$ShortName=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['ShortName']);
$art_lang=$link->query("INSERT INTO table1 (tagFriendlyName,tagShortName) VALUES ('$FriendlyName','$ShortName');");
$insert_id=$link->insert_id;
while($get_lang=$get_lang_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     $language = $get_lang['langISOCode'];
     $where .= "($insert_id,'".$_POST[$language]."',".$get_lang['langID']."),";
}
$where = rtrim($where, ",");
$art_lang_m=$link->query("INSERT INTO Table2 (tagMRootID,tagMDispName,tagMLang) values $where");
$get_lang_id->free();
$link->close();
echo "DONE";
```

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of your stored languages like this

```
$ARR_LANGUAGES = ("AR", "EN", "KU");
```

now check that isset the language

```
foreach($ARR_LANGUAGE as $language)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$language]))
    {
         echo $language." is Set through post !! <br/>"
    }
    else
    {
        echo $language." is Not Set !! <br/>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a naming convention like:

```
name="language[EN]"
```

Then, in PHP, you can loop over the associative array `$_POST['language']` (assuming you add `method="post"` to your form).

```
foreach ($_POST['language'] as $lang => $user_input) {
    do_something_with($lang, $user_input);
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm using jquery to post data.

Comment: @TarekSawah — Assuming you are just using `$().serialize()` on the form, that doesn't make a difference. If you aren't, then the solution is still to use this naming convention, you would just be doing it in your JavaScript when manually constructing the data you are sending.

Comment: This is actually the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can just loop through all your form data, and excluse fields you don't need (such as the submit button), so you can create a fully dynamic query. Here is a quick example:

```
$exclude = array('submit');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, $exclude)) {
        $query .= $key . "=". $value;
    }
}
```